# Does a bootstrap row have to always equal 12?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The reason I ask is because I am using a php function via a plugin (within WordPress) that creates rows of data...

It appears that boostrap happily loads a column of say 'col-sm-6' but my question is really one for 'standards'.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, it **doesn't have** to be equal 12. As stated in the **[Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)** docs:

> Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases

...which means in short that it **can** scale up to 12, but it's not required to be 12 always.

Therefore, it's ok to use only 6 columns, depending on your requirements.

Comment: Interesting. I always used to total 12. Thanks for your comment

Comment: You usually want to use all the available columns, in order to avoid dead blank space in the screen. But sometimes you just want it that way. Just think about the **offset** feature, where you just skip some columns.